# Remove javascript codes in parsing a webpage

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

When capturing the content of a webpage by `CURL` or `file_get_contents`, What is the easiest way to remove inline javascrip codes. I am thinking of regex to remove everything between   tags; but regex is not a reliable method for this purpose.

Is there a better way to parse an html page (just removing javascript codes)? If regex is still the best option, what is the most reliable command to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and its [`removeChild()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) function. Something like the following should get you going.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('index.html');

$page = $doc->documentElement;

// we retrieve the chapter and remove it from the book
$scripts = $page->getElementsByTagName('script');
foreach($scripts as $script) {
   $page->removeChild($script);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: I was avoiding DOM, as it is slower than regex, and here I do not need many parse functions. However, it seems to be quite reliable for tiny parsing too (and then needed)!

Comment: Faster and less reliable, or slower and more reliable? The eternal question.

Comment: It is not only matter of sacrificing speed in favor of reliability. DOMDocument does not simply parse any html page, and most of times it just returns with bunches of errors. For instance, save the html code of the present page as index.html, and run the above-mentioned code. It will return lots of errors of "DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch"...

Comment: Won't this solution miss tag attribute javascript?  For example, <body onload="alert('hello');">

Comment: @peabody yes, it only answers what the OP asked for. You would need to add code to find and remove the relevant attributes if that is what you want to do: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php